# Impossible to rewrite my Partitions Table with my two Linux partitions although there is no ovelap

Tags: boot, data-recovery, partitioning, testdisk

Due to a bug created by Windows 10, I am trying to rewrite the partitions table of my hard disk with TestDisk. I had a Dual Boot environment (Windows / Ubuntu) and I had two Linux partitions (Partition type 83). A partition was with Ubuntu 13 and the other one with Ubuntu 15.04.

There is no overlap and as a result, I don't understand the reason why TestDisk refuses any structure that will contain my two Linux partitions: within the "Quick Search" screen, if I only select one of the two Linux partitions, it says to me "Structure OK" but I try to select both Linux partitions, it says to me "Bad structure". May you help me?

**When I try to select my two Linux partitions:**

```
TestDisk 6.14, Data Recovery Utility, July 2013
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sda - 750 GB / 698 GiB - CHS 91201 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
 P FAT32 LBA                0  32 33  3263 170 43   52428800 [RECOVERY]
 * HPFS - NTFS           3263 170 44 39744  19 19  586057728 [OS]
 P HPFS - NTFS          39744  19 20 51954 195 57  196164776 [DATA]
   HPFS - NTFS          39744  19 20 51954 209 31  196165632 [DATA]
>L Linux                51954 209 32 70244 108  8  293822464
 L Linux                70244 108  9 90445 190 49  324534272
 L Linux Swap           90446 195 54 91201  52 51   12120064

Structure: Bad. Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
*=Primary bootable  P=Primary  L=Logical  E=Extended  D=Deleted
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type, P: list files,
     Enter: to continueubuntu@ubuntu:~$
ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock, 150 GB / 140 GiB
```

**When I try to only select my first Linux partition:**

```
Disk /dev/sda - 750 GB / 698 GiB - CHS 91201 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
 P FAT32 LBA                0  32 33  3263 170 43   52428800 [RECOVERY]
 * HPFS - NTFS           3263 170 44 39744  19 19  586057728 [OS]
 P HPFS - NTFS          39744  19 20 51954 195 57  196164776 [DATA]
   HPFS - NTFS          39744  19 20 51954 209 31  196165632 [DATA]
 L Linux                51954 209 32 70244 108  8  293822464
   Linux                70244 108  9 90445 190 49  324534272
>L Linux Swap           90446 195 54 91201  52 51   12120064

Structure: Ok.  Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
*=Primary bootable  P=Primary  L=Logical  E=Extended  D=Deleted
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type,
     Enter: to continue
SWAP2 version 1, pagesize=4096, 6205 MB / 5918 MiB
```

**When I try to only select my second Linux partition:**

```
Disk /dev/sda - 750 GB / 698 GiB - CHS 91201 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
 P FAT32 LBA                0  32 33  3263 170 43   52428800 [RECOVERY]
 * HPFS - NTFS           3263 170 44 39744  19 19  586057728 [OS]
 P HPFS - NTFS          39744  19 20 51954 195 57  196164776 [DATA]
   HPFS - NTFS          39744  19 20 51954 209 31  196165632 [DATA]
   Linux                51954 209 32 70244 108  8  293822464
>L Linux                70244 108  9 90445 190 49  324534272
 L Linux Swap           90446 195 54 91201  52 51   12120064

Structure: Ok.  Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
*=Primary bootable  P=Primary  L=Logical  E=Extended  D=Deleted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mission accomplished ! I have used TestDisk to successfully restore all my partitions. Having said that, I have to confess that I was a bit lucky. Yesterday, I launched TestDisk after having not used it during a few days. For an unknown reason, the application behaved differently compared to the way it used to behave: indeed, TestDisk take at least one minute to display the “Quick Search” screen whereas it was immediately displayed the previous times I used it. During this minute, the TestDisk screen displays the values of the Start and End points of each partition. However, during this minute, the End point values of the first Linux partitions were values that were never given by any other TestDisk screen or by any other command or application before. I had the feeling that those values, which were temporarily displayed, were the correct ones: the point is that those values allowed having space between the two Linux / Logical partitions.

Then, I edited a Log TestDisk file, which is a simple ASCII file. I added two new lines to this text file: those lines were about the two missing Logical partitions. Naturally, for the first Linux partitions, I entered the End point values that had just mysteriously appeared just before the “Quick Search” screen. The next step was to load the updated log file in TestDisk. The Disk Structure was immediately accepted by the application. Then, I only had to ask to TestDisk to rewrite the partitions table by taking into consideration the values given by the Log file. After that, I just had to restart my computer, to launch Boot-Repair from an Ubuntu Live-CD session, to restart again my computer and at last, to use a working GRUB, to launch Ubuntu and to enjoy Ubuntu, which was back to life!

For information, the values that were finally used to successfully rewrite the partitions table with TestDisk are available here at the very end of the first sheet ("Feuil1"): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16bOgee0CIObZORWjyKw7l7do8czfdfB5PEGZj6OhWjc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

TestDisk is a tool of last resort. The sorts of problems that Windows partitioning tools create can often be fixed with less drastic measures. For experts, wonders can be worked with `fdisk` or `sfdisk`. For those of intermediate skill, my own FixParts (part of the `gdisk` package in Ubuntu) can fix many problems. See the [FixParts documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) for information on how to use it. [This Ubuntu forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1192598) has some basic information on using `sfdisk` to fix problems. That said, unless I've misread your output, I don't think FixParts will be able to recover all your partitions -- at least, not by itself. `sfdisk` could probably do it, but that will take more expertise.

Unfortunately, since you presented no information on what your partition table currently looks like, I'm working blind on some critical details. I recommend you read the links I've provided (and especially my FixParts page), compare it to what you've got, and perhaps see what these tools make of your disk. If you want more help, edit your question to include the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` and add a comment to this answer to flag my attention.

As to the problem you're facing, my suspicion is that the cause is that you're trying to recover two partitions as being logical when there are no free sectors between them. The usual structure of an MBR disk requires at least one free sector in-between any two logical partitions, so what you're trying to do won't work. (Some tools, such as `sfdisk`, have ways around this limitation, but most will choke on it.) Given your disk layout, it may not be possible to include all your partitions in an MBR setup except by first resizing one or two partitions. Depending on the current partition state, that may be an extremely dangerous proposition.

Another possibility might be to convert to GPT. (Or perhaps the disk was originally -- and perhaps still is -- in GPT form, and you just told TestDisk you wanted to use MBR?) GPT doesn't have the gap-between-partitions issue of MBR, so you should be able to include all your partitions in this form. The downside is that *if* the disk currently uses MBR and successfully boots Windows, you'll have to jump through some hoops to get Windows booting in EFI mode. (You'll also need a computer with EFI/UEFI firmware.) Even if the disk currently uses MBR, converting to GPT might enable you to resize partitions. You could then convert back to MBR to get Windows booting again. Any such conversion -- even a temporary one -- would be likely to require you to re-install boot loaders.

Whatever you do, *do not make changes to your partition table* until you fully understand what's going on. Many people in situations similar to yours have done irreparable harm to their data by rushing in with an inadequate understanding of the problem. Also, if you don't already have good backups, make them. Even a competent person could easily end up losing data trying to fix your problem.

---

**EDIT:**

Given the new information you've presented, it appears that Windows has completely erased two partitions from your partition table. The good news is that you've got excellent data on the start and end points of the filesystems, so you should be able to recover. (The fact that TestDisk found filesystems means that your data are probably intact, just inaccessible.)

No matter how you do this, I ***strongly*** recommend that you begin by making a complete low-level backup of the disk. If my calculations are correct, your disk is 700GiB in size, so you should be able to do a backup onto a disk with at least that much free space with a command like this:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/to/lots/of/space/backup-sda.img bs=4096
```

This operation is likely to take a few hours to complete. Be *very* careful with this command, and in particular with the `if=` and `of=` options, which specify the input and output files, respectively. With that done....

IIRC, `sfdisk` can create an extended partition with logical partitions that have no space between them, so you can try recovering by first creating an `sfdisk` text file with the following command:

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda > partitions-sda.txt
```

The contents of `partitions-sda.txt` should be similar to the first block of output on your spreadsheet. You can then load that file into a text editor and add information on your two missing partitions. The tricky parts are the start and size values, but you seem to have already computed them, so you just need to create appropriate lines for them with the right values specified. You'll also need to adjust the start point for the extended partition so that it contains your two "new" (recovered) partitions. When you're done, you can write the result back out to disk:

```
sfdisk -f /dev/sda < partitions-sda.txt
```

This *should* work. If it doesn't, though, then you may have made a mistake, or perhaps I'm mistaken about `sfdisk`'s capabilities, or maybe `sfdisk` has changed.

Once this is done, I recommend checking your filesystems. You may also want to shrink the end of the first Ubuntu partition so that there's a small gap between it and the next one. You can probably do this with GParted -- although it's possible that GParted will refuse to work on the disk because of this issue. In this case, you may need to back up the partition, delete it, create a new one in its place, and restore the data.

An alternative to this procedure is to buy a new disk and copy the partitions over one at a time. You can even use `dd` with the `skip` option to read the "lost" filesystems from the disk without re-creating partitions around them -- but you must be very precise when specifying the start points.

Yet another alternative is to use TestDisk to recover the first Linux partition, shrink it slightly with GParted, and then run TestDisk again to recover the second Linux partition. This should work, but there's a small chance that TestDisk or GParted with write something to the area occupied by the second filesystem while it's officially unallocated, thus damaging it.

Telling TestDisk to recover the disk as GPT is yet another option, but that will render Windows unbootable, at least until you jump through more hoops. If your computer is BIOS-based (rather than EFI-based, as most post-2011 computers are), you won't be able to boot Windows at all from GPT. If you go with this option, you'll need to write a new boot loader to the disk.

---

**EDIT 2:**

In response to your latest questions:

- Yes, you'd reverse the `dd` command to restore the backup.
- Note that the first `sfdisk` command I presented used a `-d` option and the second used a `-f` option.
- The whole point of using `sfdisk` is that, IIRC, it's one of the rare programs that can create two logical partitions with no space between them. It does this by writing EBRs consecutively on the disk, before either logical partition. Although EBRs are important disk data structures, you shouldn't normally be trying to modify them by hand; just let `sfdisk` (or GParted or whatever) handle them.
- My guess is that your Linux partitions were originally primaries and Windows deleted them; but maybe they were logicals that were created by `sfdisk` or something else that can create two logical partitions next to each other, and when the Windows partitioner saw that it choked and deleted them rather than try to create something it couldn't.

Comment: Please find some answers to your questions in the answer I've just posted.

Comment: As explained in my last answer, I have finally entirely solved the problem with TestDisk.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the start and end sectors in your screenshots, please. In the first one you select the first Linux partition of which the structure is apparently bad. In the second screenshot you select the Linux swap file which is good. In the third screenshot you select the second Linux partition which is also OK. According to your screenshots you never select two partitions at the same time. AFAIK it is impossible to select two partitions at the same time so you can't even do that.
So you have to repair your first Linux partition only. BTW: on the third screenshot some important information is clipped off.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks though I am afraid you don’t understand.« > » is a cursor, which allows the user to assign « P », « L » or « * » to any partition. How do you have to understand the screens? The three first partitions are selected and they are considred as « Primary » (first column is P), which makes sense. On the first screen, it means that BOTH Linux partitions are selected as logical, which makes sense too.

The message “Structure bad” is about... the structure.

Sectors are OK: they have been calculated (LBA/CHS) and checked by several persons. Find details here and here.

Can anyone advise me?